# (Gmail) How to get first 500 threads based on sender

Tags: google-apps-script

I see in the Google documentation that you can pull emails from your entire inbox by using getInboxThreads() OR if they have a label attached to them, with a script like this:

```
const label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("my label name");
const inboxThreads = label.getThreads(0, 500);
```

However, I want to be able to get threads based on the email addresses of one or more senders, and limit the search to the first 500 messages. However, my code below is not working:

```
const sender = GmailApp.search('from:myemail@gmail.com');
const inboxThreads = sender.getThreads(0, 500);
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work? I think the "getThreads()" funciton only works on labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `I want to be able to get threads based on the email addresses of one or more senders, and limit the search to the first 500 messages`, in this case, how about using `GmailApp.search(query, start, max)`?

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const sender = GmailApp.search('from:myemail@gmail.com');
const inboxThreads = sender.getThreads(0, 500);
```

#### To:

```
const inboxThreads = GmailApp.search('from:myemail@gmail.com', 0, 500);
```

or, if you want to retrieve 0 to 500 emails from multiple email addresses, how about the following modification?

```
const emails = ["###email1###", "###email2###",,,];
const inboxThreads = GmailApp.search(emails.map(e => `from:${e}`).join(" OR "), 0, 500);
```

or, if you want to retrieve 0 to 500 emails for each email address, how about the following modification?

```
const emails = ["###email1###", "###email2###",,,];
const res = emails.map(e => GmailApp.search(`from:${e}`, 0, 500));
```

#### Reference:

- [search(query, start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery,-start,-max)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getEmailsBasedUponSenders() {
  const senders = ["email address 1", "email address 2","email address 3"];
  let ts = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  let msgs = [];
  ts.forEach(t => {
    t.getMessages().filter(m => ~senders.indexOf(m.getFrom())).forEach(m => {msgs.push([m.getFrom(), m.getSubject(), m.getPlainBody()])});
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(msgs));
}
```